# Display Time Zone description in to_char() in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as timestamp with LOCAL time zone), 'YYYY-MM-DD, HH24:MI:SS TZR') from dual
```

This return output as

```
2015-08-06, 04:09:10 +05:30
```

Anyone have any clue to get output as follows

```
2015-08-06, 04:09:10 IST
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In general you cannot show time zone of `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` value, because it is always your current local time zone by definition.

`+05:30` is your current time zone, you can verify by this:

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM dual;
```

You cannot do

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'IST';
```

Because `IST` is also used for "Iceland Standard Time", "Ireland Standard Time", "Israel Standard Time", etc.

However, you can use this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD, HH24:MI:SS TZD') FROM dual;
```

Note, `TZD` means "Daylight savings information". In case India has Daylight saving your TZD may change.

Answer (score -2):

I have converted the TIMESTAMP To UTC and added 5.5 hrs to it. Like below

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(systimestamp) + (5.5/24))|| ' IST' FROM DUAL;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This will fail when the user changes his local time zone (what he can do at any time)